# How to set different weight variables in multiple rnn layers in tensorflow?

Tags: python, parameters, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Hi I'm writing a "many(input) to many(output)" rnn code to deal with character prediction. For this, I set my hidden layer parameter as follows. Three hidden layers and each of them has 100, 200, and 300 hidden units.

```
hidden layers= [100,200,300]
```

My code is this.

```
# parameters.
hiddenLayers = [100,200,300]
timeStep = 20 # sequence length
inputDimension = 38 (# of English alphabet + symbols)
outputDimension = 38 (# of English alphabet + symbols)
input_x = tf.placeholder(tyf.float64, [None, timeStep, inputDimension])

# make weights
w1 = tf.get_variable("w1",[hiddenUnits[0],hiddenUnits[1] ],initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
w2 = tf.get_variable("w2",[hiddenUnits[1],hiddenUnits[2] ],initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
w3 = tf.get_variable("w3",[hiddenUnits[2],outputDimension ],initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
# make biases
b1 = tf.get_variable("b1",[hiddenUnits[1]], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
b2 = tf.get_variable("b2",[hiddenUnits[2]], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
b3 = tf.get_variable("b3",[outputDimension], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

def cell_generator(hiddenUnits):
    return rnn_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hiddenUnits, forget_bias=1.0)

rnn_cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell_generator(_) for _ in hiddenLayers])
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn_cell, input_x, dtype=tf.float64)
```

Now I have 3 hidden layers and each of them has different number of hidden units.
When I printed out "outputs" and "states" and they say liek this. (I didn't run a session.)

```
print(outputs)
Tensor("rnn/transpose:0", shape=(?, 20, 300), dtype=float64)

print(states)
(LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_2:0' shape=(?, 100) dtype=float64>, h=<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_3:0' shape=(?, 100) dtype=float64>),
LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_4:0' shape=(?, 200) dtype=float64>, h=<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_5:0' shape=(?, 200) dtype=float64>),
LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_6:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float64>, h=<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_7:0' shape=(?, 300) dtype=float64>))
```

I thought that "output" should hold every output from 3 hidden layers but it has only last hidden layer so I got lost where to multiply 1st and 2nd weights. So now I have questions.

1. Can I use "states" variables which hold 3 hidden layers so that I can multiply my 3 weights and add 3 biases to each of the last states.

for example...

```
hidden2 = tf.matmul(state[0],w1) + b1
hidden3 = tf.matmul(state[1],w2) + b2
final_output = tf.matmul(state[2],w3) + b3
# and do the loss calculation for training...
```

2. Is there any way that I can use "output" variable in order to apply my weights and biases to that cell?
3. Or is there any other alternative ways that I can use my weights and biases? Maybe initialize weights and biases in the previous steps(before toss the basicRNNCell to the MultiRNNcell)?

I really want to set the different number of hidden layers and units and apply them with my predetermined weight and bias parameters. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that "output" should hold every output from 3 hidden layers but it has only last hidden layer so I got lost where to multiply 1st and 2nd weights. So now I have questions.

By calling `MultiRNNCell` on 3 cells, you create a multilayered network, where each cell is a single layer (just like in normal fully connected networks you can have multiple layers), and each layer feeds into the next one, like:

```
input -> cell1 -> cell2 -> cell3 -> output
```

So the output of your RNN is the output of cell3, hence the `(?, 20, 300)` shape. The only variables you need to get the final output is `w3` and `b3`, like

```
final_output = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(outputs, w3) + b3)
```

which gives you the predicted distribution over your classes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Then it sounds like since multiRNNCell gathers multiple hidden layers into one big network, I may not be able to access one of those layers after building it except the last layer. I would rather generate multiple dynamic_rnn cells (instead of using multiRNNCell) and use my predetermined weights and biases to those outputs. Thanks!